# Какие ограничения накладывает бесплатная версия unity?

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу разработать приложение (без рынка и продаж) для  пк и android для внутреннего использования внутри компании. Какие ограничения накладывает бесплатная версия unity ?

Comment: Проголосовал за закрытие, юридические вопросы - это очень тонкие материи, которые вообще никак не касаются данного сайта про **софт**. Да и не думаю, что найдется храбрец, что возьмет на себя ответственность отвечать на такой вопрос. Вам просто нужно обратиться с таким вопросом в поддержку Unity - там вам с радостью помогут.

Comment: аналогично за закрытие вопроса, хоть и дал ответ автору

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO не является подходящим сайтом для таких вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Могу ли я использовать Personal для разработки коммерческих проектов?**

> Если годовой оборот вашей компании составляет больше 100 000 $ или же
>   если вам удалось привлечь на разработку более 100 000 $, вы не имеете
>   права использовать Unity Personal, будь то для прототипирования или в
>   иных целях — см. наше соглашение с конечным пользователем
>
> Вы можете пользоваться Unity Plus, если ваш годовой оборот до вычета
>   налогов не превышает 200 тыс. $, в противном случае вам необходима
>   Unity Pro.

Думаю не сложно зайти и почитать https://store.unity.com/ru/products/unity-personal